# How to parse JSON GET method in android with user input parameters?

Tags: android, json

How to get data from JSON with user input parameters in android?

Comment: Hi Surya, look at the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and you should post your complete description about the issue.

Comment: @ B Kumar, How to parse JSON using GET method?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question or you can post your JSON also

Comment: For example: In this JSON http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/                                       How to get Particular contact name and his details by passing name using JSON GET method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the below code will give you the feasible solution for your problem,

Paste the below code in your Java file

```
private static JSONObject get(Context ctx, String sUrl) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {

        URL url = new URL(sUrl);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
                "Basic " + encodedAuthentication);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8,*");
        Log.d("Get-Request", url.toString());
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            Log.d("Get-Response", stringBuilder.toString());
            return new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
}

private static String buildSanitizedRequest(String url,
                                            Map<String, String> mapOfStrings) {

    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
    uriBuilder.encodedPath(url);
    if (mapOfStrings != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mapOfStrings.entrySet()) {
            Log.d("buildSanitizedRequest", "key: " + entry.getKey()
                    + " value: " + entry.getValue());
            uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    String uriString;
    try {
        uriString = uriBuilder.build().toString(); // May throw an
        // UnsupportedOperationException
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "Exception" + e);
    }

    return uriBuilder.build().toString();

}
```

And your Json calling part should look like this

```
public static JSONObject exampleGetMethod(Context ctx, String sUrl,String yourName) throws JSONException, IOException {
    Map<String, String> request = new HashMap<String, String>();
    request.put("yourName", yourName);

    sUrl = sUrl + "yourApiName";
    return get(ctx, buildSanitizedRequest(sUrl, request));
}
```

In the above code - startDate, endDate,yourName and username are the input parameters.
sUrl is the API url + API name
Finally when you call     `exampleGetMethod(Context,String,String,String,String,String);`
you will get the JSON response of requested URL.

If you want to get the specific array value from the response you need to think of below logic

```
JSONArray a = response.getJSONArray("contacts");
JSONObject needyArray;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if(a.getJSONObject(i).optString("name").equals("kumar")){
            needyArray = a.getJSONObject(i);
            break;
        }
}
```

Now the needyArray JSONObject variable have the data of particular person(kumar as the example)

Comment: For example: In this JSON api.androidhive.info/contacts How to get Particular contact name and his details by passing name.

Comment: Hey Surya, I edited my answer slightly and the below link may helps a lot to you, just try this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Thanks. But it displays all json data. how to get particular details by passing input in json object? for example if want to see "kumar" details. how to pass "kumar" in json object?

Comment: I have edited my answer, I guess that will fix your needs.

Comment: ok Thanks @  B Kumar. Sorry for inconvenience. Im new student to android.